# Issues using Ansible URI module - Getting 401 even when authentication credentials are added

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using Ansible's URI module to call a simple GET endpoint but I am getting a 401 error message as shown below.

[image]

Here is the playbook configuration

```
  - name: Elasticsearch Cluster health Check
    uri:
      url: https://elastichost:9200/_cluster/health?&pretty
      url_password : xxxxxxx
      url_username : xxxxxx
      validate_certs : no
      method: GET
      body_format: json
      force_basic_auth: yes
      return_content: yes
      headers:
         Content-Type: "application/json" 
    register: showhealth
    tags: NonProd

  - name: Show Elasticsearch Health
    debug: var=showhealth  
    tags: NonProd
```

Any inputs on how to resolve

Comment: HTTP Error Code 401 "_semantically means "unauthorised", the user does not have valid authentication credentials for the target resource_", the user or password might be incorrect.

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure of the username and password. The same username and password works when hitting the endpoint using a CURL or Postman

Comment: (a) Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page (b) without seeing an equivalent `curl` invocation, it's hard to compare apples to apples (c) if you try that task against `nc -l -v 9200`, you'll observe that a `method: GET` with `body_format: json` actually sends a _body_ of `null` along with the `GET` request, which could be jamming up a request to a health endpoint (that surely does not expect a payload sent to it)

Answer (score 0):

specific issue with elastic. elastic is secure, you need token or certificate to connect to api.

And ofc, your's user need correct right.

exemple

```
- name: Create update_user
  uri:
    url: 'uri'
    method: POST
    user: elasticuser
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    body: '{{ item.body }}'
    client_cert: 'certificate.crt'
    client_key: 'certificate.key'
    password: '{{ elastic_password }}'
    validate_certs: false
    return_content: true
```

Comment: Are you claiming that every connection to elastic requires TLS credentials, because that is for sure not true, and OP even said they are able to successfully connect with  `curl`, making it an especially suspicious answer to this question

Comment: Why suspicions ? If x pack is enabled, elastic node doestnt accept unencrypted communication.and need thrusted certificate. the best practice is use apikey on user with limited right user.

Comment: And i have miss comment who speak about curl.